# Fetch call returning 401: Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, basic-authentication

I am attempting to fetch a php app hosted on AWS with basic authentication. I followed tutorials and attempted other answers such as encrypting the username and password using btoa

Currently, this is my code:

```
let h = new Headers(); 
        let url = "URL"
        let user = "USER"
        let pass = "PASS"
        let encoded = window.btoa(`${user}:${pass}` )


        let auth = ('Basic ' + encoded)



        console.log(auth)

        h.append('Authorization', auth)
        console.log(h.has('Authorization'))
        fetch(url, {
            headers: h
        }) .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a `WWW-Authenticate` header coming back with the 401 or any other details on the response? It's difficult to tell whether the problem is your credentials not being the type of credentials the app expects or the credentials being incorrect.

Comment: @Amer: Would you mind to change `encrypting the username and password using boa`to `encoding the username and password using boa` to make clear that base64 encoding has nothing to do with encryption